# my iPhone 7 plus won't wake up after sleep

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

as you see in Title, my iphone won't wake up after it goes to sleep mode, whether i put my phone to sleep or its automatic goes to sleep mode.

However, once it goes to sleep, i try to tap on Home button , it vibrate once(but still screen black) then wont even vibrate even click on home button.

my temporary workaround: i hard reboot it (pressing volume down+power) but then i have to keep my screen on to use it, once i dont it goes to sleep mode or freeze or whatever for ever untill i hard reboot it again ..

- i tried hard reset (just settings)
- i tried hard reset (with data and everything)

still did not helped me, my last attempt would be hard reset it using itunes... any help i would appreciate it, and please i would know what is the reason that happining, as its my first IOS device ever, its just disappointing me..

IOS version: 12.4 (latist)
thanks in advance